# Matlab's matrix size limit simple issue

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am now running a function which will create a 591000 x 1500 matrix which I am planning to use to train an Svm classifier in matlab. I am using Matlab 2012 7.14.0.739 (R2012a) GLNXA64. My final matrix will have 886500000 elements.

Where can I know if my matrix will fit my Matlab's memory requirements? how can I know how many bytes my matrix with 886500000 elements will use? the matrix size limit in Matlab is per matrix or it considers the bytes consumed by all the matrices I am using in my code?

Comment: The default precision is `double`, which is 8 bytes per element. For a 64 bit OS and 64 bit MATLAB the size limit is not determined by MATLAB, it's determined by the amount of RAM your machine has.

Comment: Approximately 7GB will your array be. You need that amount of *free* RAM.